# File Beat not able to connect with logstash from another instance (ELK stack)

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have ELK stack on one EC2 instance which is running perfectly. In my client server, I have installed filebeat which is supposed to send the log data to logstash from the client server.
But I don't see any data in the Elasticsearch (or Kibana)
When i checked logs in filebeat i see the below error message:
"ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): x509: cannot validate certificate for  because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"

Below is my filebeat.yml file:

filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log
- /var/log/*.log

**#Logstash output**

output.logstash:

# The Logstash hosts

hosts: [":5044"]

bulk_max_size: 1024

# Optional SSL. By default is off.

# List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications

ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"]

I have followed the steps from the below article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have generated the self-signed certificate in ELK stack server and have copied the same to my client server.

Can anyone please help me in showing what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, your certificate doesn't include the IP addresses of the machines involved.

A quick google search for the message found [this discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/x509-cannot-validate-certificate-for-192-168-129-33-because-it-doesnt-contain-any-ip-sans/98435) in Elastic's support portal.